# QGIS - online Bing basemap shifts when map is exported as a PDF

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2.18, bing-maps

Using QGIS 2.18 “Las Palmas”

Created a map to print using the “New Print Composer” extension.

When working on this all polygons are perfectly in place.

Once the map is saved as a PDF/Image the polygons shift.

Extra info: Bing map (Base Map from Open Layers Plugin) and all polygons are set to ESPG:29902 TM65/Irish Grid

Comment: there was a problem with the basemap shifting are you sure it's not the case here

Comment: Are you by any chance using the Open Layers Plugin to load your basemaps? Basemaps shifting in the print composer was a known issue with that plugin. You could use the Quick Map Services plugin instead. Note: you need to add the contributed services pack to get Bing base maps. Another option is to add a Bing base map as an xyz tile layer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Where do I find the contributed services pack to get Bing base maps?

Comment: Open the menu for the QuickMapServices plugin > Settings > More Services > Get contributed pack.

Answer (score 0):

This commonly happens when working with raster basemaps, especially if they come from online sources.

Your polygon didn't shift, it was the raster behind it that shifted. Rasters and on-the-fly projections are not good friends (at least with the technology we use nowadays, hopefully this will change in the future).

If you want the raster to stay in place, you need to make sure that the raster source is in the same projection as the current project.  This could mean you need to make a local copy of the Bing map (check if you the licence allows you to do it first) and reproject it (using the geoprocessing tools) to the current projection you are working in.

Then it shouldn't move.